# FROM_UNIXTIME() returns epoch, not the date

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to search my DB for records with a certain day recorded against them, where that record is a UNIX timestamp. Here is an example of one of those timestamps:

> 1389026993

That date is Mon, 06 Jan 2014 16:49:53 GMT

However I'm finding that my select statement

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME('join_date')
```

returns this:

> 1970-01-01 01:00:00

Am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quote **otherwise you are passing a string as the parameter**.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(join_date)
```

Comment: So simple... (both me and the solution!). Thanks